# Talend - Component that checks for any failure in multiple tRunjob

Tags: exception, talend

I did some search before posting this, couldn't find the talend component that will do the "Any failure" check mentioned in the image. any input is appreciated.

I have multiple tRunjobs which has to execute one after the other "on Subjob OK" but upon failure of any of the tRunjob, first the job has to catch the failure log and send a mail and then abort, I have tried to put this as a image, I'm particularly looking for the component "Any failure" which will check for any failure on any of the tRunjob. which component will do that?

[image: on failure of any trunjob]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a similar approach in the past. This depends how the three jobs are called - I called them from one "handle all the stuff" job and used subjobs. E.g. this would lead to "Any Failure" is also the job which is calling the three subjobs.

Usually I only add a *tLogCatcher* in the main job which is calling the three other jobs. Then I make sure that the components in the three other jobs are set to throw errors if something goes wrong. All error handling would be done then in the main job.

Comment: Thanks for responding, So do you add all the checkpoints in the sub jobs? In case of any failure whether the subjobs can start from the point of failure?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with checkpoints. Usually we try to design the jobs restartable and use the error logging to know if the job failed.

Comment: I'm using open studio, but can you tell which version has restartable option and how to enable that?

Comment: I don't know about restartable options. Where have you gotten this info?

Answer (score 0):

Talend will not support a closed loop in your job.. So your best options are
--> create a joblet or use the same code for all 3 subjobs onsubjob error.
Or
--> use tPostjob and send an email based on the status of the each subjobs with tDie onsubjoberror.

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you saying, I should catch the status of each subjob with tDie onsubjoberror? If that is the case the job will become massive when I have multiple tRunjobs. If I can rephrase my question. what is the best way to design to achieive these below functionalities? 1) Each tRunjob should execute sequentially 2) Upon failure of any of the tRunjob, email has to be sent with the failure message 3) Job should abort 4)Upon restart, the job should restart from the point of failure. This is what is expected out of any ETL tool, any better way to implement this in talend?